# How can I test a Http Post query from linux command line

Tags: linux, http, http-post

Im testing a get request to my server using wget

i.e I created script that took argument from comandline and uses it as part of wget request

```
 #!/bin/bash
 wget  http://servername?querystring$1
```

but I need to change my server so it only accepts a http post rather than a http get. Thats fine but I dont know how to easily test it, how can I send a post with a paramter rather than a get

Im on a version of linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use --post-data :

```
wget --post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' http://server.com/auth.php
```

For more options, you can have a look to the man [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) or with `man wget`

Comment: Thankyou just what I needed

Comment: Also, more `wget` examples with set headers [here](https://www.xmodulo.com/how-to-use-custom-http-headers-with-wget.html). For example: `wget --header="Content-Type: application/json" --header="Accept: */*" --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" --post-data '"[1]"' application.local/api/theWebhook`